# Timing startup processes?

Tags: windows, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I time my startups and see what processes are taking the longest?](https://superuser.com/questions/168600/how-can-i-time-my-startups-and-see-what-processes-are-taking-the-longest)

My Windows 7 use to boot up fast and now its getting rather slow. I suspect one program is eating up all the time yet i cant tell what it is since task manager shows <40% of the cpu being used.

What can i use to track how long each process takes when my computer boots/starts up?

Note: Except for launchy which i used before my comp became slow, all my startup and services are all signed and known (broadcom, VMWare, Google Inc, Intel, etc)

Note2: I am mostly considering the time it takes after i login but i suspect the time before that is slightly slower (i dont think very much though)

-Edit after using soluto-
Its what i thought, my green and orange are < 40seconds (now 8 seconds) and the greys (cannot remove) takes up the bulk with 1m 18seconds. Yikes, i guess its from all these windows updates i apply instead of ignore like i did in the XP days. Strange thing is when i took out the 30second green/orange it cut out a lot more time (it use to say 2m38s, -30 should be 2m08s but its 1m17s)

Comment: CPU isn't always the slower, as I'm sure your aware. Look at high RAM users and that may be your issue.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I time my startups and see what processes are taking the longest?](http://superuser.com/questions/168600/how-can-i-time-my-startups-and-see-what-processes-are-taking-the-longest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event log list how long it takes to start things, https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=3253

But an easier way is to use Soluto, which is in beta right now, but I've used it on two of my systems, and it works great. http://www.soluto.com/

Answer (score 3):

Use the Reliability Monitor built into W7

http://www.msigeek.com/5518/measure-hardware-and-software-problems-using-reliability-monitor-in-windows-7

or Enable boot time logging for more in depth analysis
http://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool

See this article to see actual startup times, it was written for Vsta but is the same for W7

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/microsofts-hidden-diagnostic-tool-unlocks-vista-startup-secrets/246

.

.

Comment: @TomWij, check my edit

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a utility to do that. But, what you could do is run "MSCONFIG" and under the "General" tab, select "Diagnostic startup". This startup mode only loads the basic necessary drivers/services.

After selecting diagnostic startup, you can then restart your computer and see if it boots up any quicker. If it does, you can then go back into MSCONFIG, click the startup tab, and start adding your other startup processes back into the boot sequence. If you do this one process at a time, it should be fairly simple to single out which processes are taking the longest to load.

-Brandon