# System boot time for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, event-log, event-viewer

I am working on a system diagnostic application and I'm looking for some information on Windows boot up time in different situations.

Is there any way I can find the following information on Windows 10:
1. Boot time from Sleep/hibernate mode to login screen.
2. From login screen to seen desktop after user successfully logged in.

I have tried to find out this information from Windows Event Viewer however I am not sure what to look for!

Comment: don't code your own tool, use the already build in ETW function and [analyze boot with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1148857/174557)

Answer (score 0):

These differ from pc to pc and are not the same for the same pc.

There are many factors that determine and change depending on the usage of the system, so boot times will vary between each boot.

For the first item: you can look for a gap in events and then use the first item's timestamp as your start time. There should be a WinLogon event for the user logging in. I don't think there's one for the login screen itself.

As for determining when the user is done with the login procedure, that's really complicated, because the login procedure finishes far after the user already has control of their desktop.