# Windows 8 boot is very slow

Tags: windows-8, boot, performance

I have a two-year-old HP Notebook 15 with Windows 8.1

With [Winpatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/download.html) (like a mini [HijackThis](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/hijackthis/)) I've tried to minimize what loads on startup, yet my system seems to be booting and restarting much more slowly.  It is slow to get to the login prompt, the noticeably slow afterwards before I get the desktop.

I can't put my finger on why this is so.  I know my hard drive is not full.  About half.

Any suggestions or software recommendations?

Comment: [analyze boot with Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557). The Win10 SDK/WPT also works for Windows 8(.1).

Comment: have you made the boot analysis? have you found what slows down boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try turning on "fast startup" in the power options.
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html 
Using the command “sfc /scannow” to repair system files.
Updating the drivers to the latest version.
I used the WPT tool to check the performance before. You could check the link below and download the tool from Microsoft to check.
http://www.pallareviews.com/3361/fix-windows-8-8-1-slow-boot-startup-performance-32-64-bit/

Comment: OK, I will.  This is the kind of thing I was hoping to find in the answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how much stuff you have on your hard drive, it can be completely empty but physical wear or damage can cause mechanical failures which ultimately result in slow performance or even a faulty drive, specially on stuff that you tend to move around a lot, like a laptop. My suggestion is that you backup and perform a clean install, if that doesn't get you anywhere or worse, it fails, then get a new drive, also get an SSD if performance is a concern or you tend to move that laptop around a lot.

Comment: The laptop never moves, but the rest of your advice is good.  I do keep very good whole-system backups to guard against failure.  I particularly like your implied idea of maybe a sshd replacement drive.  I can't afford a 500 MB SSD yet.  TNX