# Immense laptop slowdown on startup

Tags: windows-7

lenovo t440p, win7 pro (it was home premium, i have no idea why it is pro after resetting to default settings), i5-4600, 8gb ram

common question but i'm stuck a bit.
firstly laptop was as fast as speedy gonzales, but for now it became extremely slow.

- no, auto launch is okay (little amount of programs)
- no, disk defrag is on my schedule
- no, there is no viruses (afaik)
  yes, i'm using ccleaner

almost the only thing that changed - hdd is used only by 60% and now i've got 4 users, but they are working separately.

what should i do and what i'm doing wrong?

thanks for watching

Comment: When the the Laptop begin getting very slow, do you notice anything happening with **HDD LED** or Hard drive activity light?

Comment: [analyze boot with WPRUI.exe/WPA.exe](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557), for Win7, use the older [1511 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771)

Answer (score 1):

Open windows task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) and keep a watch on the system resources (CPU, RAM and DISK usage). If one of them is clocking to 100%, then check that culprit.

Usually, it's the HDD that causes this slowness in the startup. If none of them is over 90% then the best bet will be to check the health of your HDD.