# Win10 Bootup: Slow bootup, high degradation events in event viewer, with invalid paths

Tags: windows-10, performance

A PC of my family members has a super slow log in process. Once things log in, things are fine, but the login takes around a minute to two minutes which seems abnormal.

Looking at the event log, it looks like there are a bunch of events of "Event ID" 101, 103, and 108 with high "degradation times".

The trick is that a lot of the paths responsible for these events don't seem to have paths that resolve, i.e.:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance" Guid="{CFC18EC0-96B1-4EBA-961B-622CAEE05B0A}" /> 
  <EventID>101</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>4002</Task> 
  <Opcode>33</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000010000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-12-18T23:09:12.400559000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>13</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{44BAF9B0-7854-0001-AE04-BB445478D301}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="3916" ThreadID="4776" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>laptop</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="StartTime">2017-12-18T23:02:24.956664000Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="NameLength">6</Data> 
  <Data Name="Name">Devic</Data> 
  <Data Name="FriendlyNameLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="FriendlyName" /> 
  <Data Name="VersionLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Version" /> 
  <Data Name="TotalTime">56436</Data> 
  <Data Name="DegradationTime">50436</Data> 
  <Data Name="PathLength">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="Path">C:\Devic</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProductNameLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProductName" /> 
  <Data Name="CompanyNameLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CompanyName" /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

How do I backsolve these to the actual entities that are failing to load in time, and speed up things?

Comment: You don't. Windows won't let you.

Comment: [analyze the boot with Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557)