# Slower boot time after partition shrink windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

On my new NVMe m.2 samsung pro drive for my ryzen system I created two separate paritions (C: and D:). I would be able to boot into windows 10 in roughly 10 seconds or less for both paritions. However, after shrinking my main boot drive parition (C:) using [aomei's parition software](https://www.disk-partition.com/) on the NVMe and extending the other partition (D:) to fill the empty space, my boot time for my main parition (C:) now takes an extra 15-20 seconds or so to boot. I do not have this issue on the D: partition. What would have caused this and can I fix it?

Comment: Run `chkdsk /x` against the volume.

Comment: what does the /x option do? Why is it important?

Comment: /x checks for and corrects errors, forcing the volume to dismount if necessary (or offers to do the check at next boot if necessary). It's the place to start if you suspect logical filesystem issues.

Comment: Ran it and seemed to fix a couple things and then 'no further action required' was displayed. However not much difference in boot time detected

Comment: Try running [CrystalDiskMark](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/) on both partitions and compare the results. I'm curious if you get different performance results?

Comment: C: - SeqRead - 3008.7 Write - 1559.3   ///////////                                                   D: - SeqRead - 3223.1 Write - 1533.3

Comment: I know I had to use a third party utility to shrink my partition because windows stated there were some unmovable files and it wouldn't shrink it.

Comment: [analyze the boot](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557)