# Long Boot (2 min 47 ) after OS reinstall

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance, operating-systems, intel-core-i7

Okey so here's the thing. I got my new Helios 300. 
After i replaced the endless os against Win8.1, later Win10, it seems that i lose more and more Speed and have a longer boot time. 
I already did all checks from hdtune, hirens, memtest etc... and they all gave me a negativ result (nothing was found). 
*I think* That all my drivers are up to date and that i adhered the installations order. 
Now i wiped the complete thing again. Any suggestions or shall i just send it back and get a new one?

Comment: What does "Loose more and more speed" mean ?  Does this occur when reading/writing to disk - if so, what kind of disk.  Have you checked your power profile and done any performance tests to show what speeds you are getting?

Comment: [analyze the slow boot with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557)