# Windows 10 - Slow winlogon boot phase on SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, performance

According to Windows Performance Recorder,
my Winlogon phase is taking 290 seconds to complete:

[image: (WPR image)]

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/969549/booting-windows-10-spends-too-long) thread suggests that it is a HDD bottleneck, but my OS is installed on a 240 GB SSD from Kingston. So I believe something else might be the problem. Any ideas? I have a secondary HDD, but I already tried to boot without it plugged in and the issue persists. Also, my SSD is half empty, so that shouldn't be a problem.

**Edit:

I´ve tracked a few misbehaving processes. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtQIv.jpg)  are some that i think might be the problem. Note how the wermgr.exe process finishes at 159 seconds. Then the sppsvc.exe process starts (likely due to a dependecy) and then the sppsvc.exe process ends at 191 seconds, roughly the end of my winlogon phase. (I've done another WPR trace and the winlogon phase took 192 seconds, just as a FYI).

Comment: What's happening in that boot phase? Drill down into the data to find what's taking so long.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I´ve tracked a few misbehaving processes. Here https://imgur.com/a/M21k1yb are some that i think might be the problem. Note how the wermgr.exe process finishes at 159 seconds. Then the sppsvc.exe process starts (likely due to a dependecy) and then the sppsvc.exe process ends at 191 seconds, roughly the end of my winlogon phase. (I've done another WPR trace and the winlogon phase took 192 seconds, just as a FYI).

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it!

Comment: What antimalware is running? Often, boot is delayed until disks, even other HDD's, are scanned. You can check that by *temporarily* disabling the software,

Comment: i don't have any antimalware (besides windows defender) running.