# Windows 10 Boot very slow

Tags: windows-10, git, visual-studio-code, chocolatey, meteor

After installing chocolatey, meteor, git and vscode my Windows boot time got up from like
5 seconds to 25 seconds.

I installed meteor by this installer https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-windows-installer-here-it-is/42416 which did not work at all and then by using chocolatey.

What i mean with boot time is the time between the windows login screen and the actual desktop after logging in.

I tried to remove some of the programs again, but the boot time keeps still now at 25 seconds
and also ran the sfcscan and dism tools which had no impact at all.

Anyone has ideas what i can do to check what is happening or where that long boot time comes from?

Comment: Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to check if there are unnecessary programs starting with Windows. Additionally you can trace the boot process as shown in this Q/A: https://superuser.com/questions/969549/booting-windows-10-spends-too-long

Comment: @Robert thx gonna try